# How to monitor Postgres for long-running transactions?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, monitoring

Can the duration of Postgres transactions be monitored? I would like to be notified of long-running transactions, primarily to spot "idle in transaction" issues before they cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [check_postgres](http://bucardo.org/wiki/Check_postgres) script from the Bucardo project offers a variety of monitoring options, including AFAIK options for long running idle transactions.

Comment: Note that it also can function as a plugin for most monitoring suites if you're motivated enough to install one.  Nagios is actually pretty easy to setup and use.  Otherwise you can wrap the check script in a shell script that emails you when things go sideways.

Answer (score 3):

you can monitor content of `pg_stat_activity` system table